# format date using moment with custom format

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs

```
var format = 'EEEE, D 'de' MMMM 'de' Y'
moment(date).format(format);
```

I have a custom format and use it with `moment` and got this

```
exp: segunda-feira, 2 de janeiro de 2017
act: Segunda-feira, 2 11 Janeiro 11 2017
```

Note the placeholder `de` in the pattern actually got parsed .. 
Is there a way for me to get the date in the expected format `segunda-feira, 2 de janeiro de 2017` using moment?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse 'Date & Time' string in Javascript which are of custom format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28002261/parse-date-time-string-in-javascript-which-are-of-custom-format)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to use `[]` square brackets to escape characters in format string, see [`format`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) docs:

> To escape characters in format strings, you can wrap the characters in square brackets.

Moreover note that there is no `EEEE` token in moment, but the single `E` represents *Day of Week (ISO)*, so in your case you will have `2222`. Use `dddd` to get the desidered output.

Here a working example:

```js
var date = '2017-01-02';
var format = 'dddd, D [de] MMMM [de] YYYY';
console.log(moment(date).format(format));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/locale/pt.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

To [escape characters](http://momentjs.com/docs/#escaping-characters) in format strings, you can wrap the characters in square brackets.

```js
var momObj = moment();
var format = 'EEEE, D [de] MMMM [de] Y';
var fString = momObj.format(format);
console.log(fString);
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.13.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```