# How to escape moment.js reserved words?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

```
// date October 10 2018 pmt 10:01
date = moment(details.date).format("MMMM DD YYYY at h:mm");
```

How to escape moment reserved keywords like a? I want the output to be `October 10 2018 at 10:01`.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [format date using moment with custom format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42638718/format-date-using-moment-with-custom-format)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just break it up into two parts?

```
const date = moment(details.date);
const formattedDate = `${date.format("MMMM DD YYYY")} at ${date.format("h:mm")}`;
```

Answer (score 6):

You can also achieve it using:

```
const date = moment(details.date);
const formattedDate = moment(date).format("DD MMM YYYY [at] hh:mm A");
```

Comment: This is the more accurate answer. It's documented in their official docs too! Thanks you @Saransh

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It is stated the same way in the official docs as @abdoo_salem pointed out. It is right on their landing: https://momentjs.com/ at "Format Dates".

Comment: I faced a weird behaviour.  When my escaped text has the character "m", the calendar does not show.  I've tried [From: ], [Fro: ], [start: ], [smell], [me] to test and it seems when there's "m", this behaviour is observed.  Any clues?